# creating a maven pom file in intellij plugin new project wizard

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-plugin, maven-plugin-development

I am writing an Intellij-idea plugin. In the plugin I want to define a new project type using new project wizard. My project should contain a specific pom file to build the project.

Any idea how I can do that? Shall I try to create the pom-file pro grammatically or shall I save a pom file as a template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by adding 
`<depends>org.jetbrains.idea.maven</depends>` to my plugin. 
Then I added a new ModuleBuilder based on [jetbrains example](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/reference_guide/project_wizard.html).

I extended MavenModuel Builder (Some methods are neccessary to override e.g. getBuilderId(), getPresentableName()).

By this you are getting a pom file very easy. By cutomizing the ModuleType and ModuleBuilder you can add things that you want to POM file.

Answer (score -1):

I generally create my IntelliJ projects using `mvn archetype:generate` then *import* it into IntelliJ.